# SQL new table with conditions

Tags: sql, string, datatables

I have a table and I want through sql to parse it into another table. The problem is that there is a condition:
There are 3 columns in old version

```
column_1 column_2 column_3
    0            1      1
    1            0      1
    1            1      1
```

And I want to store them into new table's column like :

```
new_column_1

no/yes/yes
yes/no/yes
yes/yes/yes
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. It would only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions and string concatenation, like so:

```
select t.*,
    (case when column_1 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
    || '/' || (case when column_2 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
    || '/' || (case when column_3 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as new_column_1
from mytable t
```

This uses standard string concatenation operator `||`; some databases have another operator or function.

Some databases also support `concat_ws()`, which simplifies the expression a little:

```
select t.*,
    concat_ws('/', 
        (case when column_1 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
        (case when column_2 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
        (case when column_3 = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end)
    ) as new_column_1
from mytable t
```

You can easily create a new table starting from this query, using the `insert ... select` syntax, although I would not recommend storing this derived information: instead, you can create a view, or add computed column in the original table.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

I have one more question if we replace the else= '0' with else = '' 
we will have yes/no/yes or yes/yes/ or yes//. How can I delete the '/' followed my empty line?